# Solaris 10 64bit "Broken Pipe" on TCP connection

Tags: sockets, solaris, pipe

I have create a simple Client/Server TCP connection.

If Server is already running, and Client starts aftewards everything WORK ok.

**PROBLEM** If Client starts before Server -> Client exits with "Broken Pipe"

Client code:

```
     char *sUceTcpIP="127.0.0.1";
     int  isUceTcpPort=51515;

     struct sockaddr_in dest; 
     memset(&dest, 0, sizeof(dest));
     dest.sin_family = AF_INET;
     dest.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(sUceTcpIP); 
     dest.sin_port = htons(isUceTcpPort);   

     while ((sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) <= 0) ;
     while (connect(sockfd,(struct sockaddr *) &dest,sizeof(dest)) < 0)
     { sleep(1); }
     strcpy(buffer,"sometext");
     send(sockfd,buffer,strlen(buffer)+1,0); <---- Broken Pipe
```

- gdb backtrace shows signal to be called from __so_send in /64/libc.so
- I have tried setting NON-Blockin, Linger, Reuse, Sleeps to both Client/Server but nothing works.
- I have also tried signal(SIGPIPE,SIG_IGN); on Client

**This seems like a huge BUG.**

Any HELP/workaround folks ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that we need to delete and re-create the socket:

```
connect: 
while ((sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) <= 0) ;
if (connect(sockfd,(struct sockaddr *) &dest,sizeof(dest)) < 0)
 { 
   close(sockfd); <--- close it
   sleep(1); 
   goto connect; 
 }
```

Does not make sense why we need to re-create the sock, but it work. 
If someone knows more please feel free.